# How can i solve the error : PHP Strict Standards: Declaration of CustomImportExport_Export::export()

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4, importexport, export, error-log

I get error during export product,

Error : (error_log)

[15-Jul-2016 12:24:04 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of CustomImportExport_Export::export() should be compatible with Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export::export() in /home/giritra/public_html/export_product.php on line 1047

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the error states your declaration needs to be compatible with the class you're extending. This means that functions needs to have same number of properties passed.

The original class `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export` have method `export()` but it doesn't receives any parameters. In your class your method has an extra parameter `$destination`. Remove the parameter from method definition and the error will be resolved.

On the other hand it looks like you're doing this wrong. You're not using Magento module concept, and you're declaring multiple classes in one file which AFAIK will fail to autoload in PSR-4. You really should do this as a module, not a file in public place where it'll be available for everyone.

Comment: Actually am host my site, completely developed from localhost right after i did hosting.

Comment: i don't know any other files or missing or not

Comment: help me about this error

Comment: regard this line @ The original class Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export have method export() but it doesn't receives any parameters. In your class your method has an extra parameter $destination. Remove the parameter from method definition and the error will be resolved.

Comment: the same error i get it again

Comment: Note : Export is working, only thing bulk export not working, which means 100's records is exported, but 1000,s of product not exported, is any memory error.

Comment: You've ran out of memory which means you need to increase `MEMORY_LIMIT` in your `php.ini` or change your code to consume less memory.

Comment: is this right    http://i.imgur.com/xXEcCL0.png

Comment: Let you know one thing, in my site consists 25,000 products.